# Cross browser alternatives to eval

Tags: javascript, eval

My html page dynamically loads pages via Ajax for dynamic panels on the page. I need the script tags in the dynamically loaded pages to be executed. I fixed the code from a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml). It works fine on FF/Safari/Chrome.

But dom nodes of type script work differently on IE. -- I can't seem to add text to a script node in IE 7:

```
//  variable "data" holds the script element's content from an
//  incoming html page loaded via ajax   
var script = document.createElement("script");        
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data)); // doesn't work on ie      

// also doesn't work on IE 7:
script.innerHTML = data;
script.innerText = data;
```

Any ideas for getting the sw to work on IE? (Other than using eval.)

Comment: Why don't you want to use eval?

Comment: Apparently this weird voodoo works in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703705/how-do-i-inject-javascript-to-a-page-on-ie-8/#704432.  However, not sure if this would be better than eval.

Comment: @pat: That boils down to `script.text = data;`.  No, it's not better than `eval`.

Comment: It's slightly better than eval because it's not evaluated in the local scope of the function where it was called, so it can't manipulate 'private' values. Same deal with `new Function(data)()`.

Comment: @SLaks -- eval is not preferred due to the scope issue as @no says. Code purity is also a nice to have, but I was willing to accept eval if I couldn't find an alternative. @Pat's and your answer of using .text is the right answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simple call `eval(data)`.

Although it is true that `eval` should usually be avoided, this is one of the few exceptions.

---

**EDIT**: Without `eval`, [you can do it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703705/how-do-i-inject-javascript-to-a-page-on-ie-8/#704432):

```
    var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
    scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptNode.text = data;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptNode); 
    document.head.removeChild(scriptNode); //Optional
```

Comment: Is there any kind of formal reference explaining the `text` property of a script element? I can't seem to find this anywhere... Chrome has both script.text and script.textContent, I wonder if some browsers only have textContent?

Comment: I found a ref to text attribute here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535892(v=VS.85).aspx  But I wouldn't try it on a non-IE browser. The fact that appendChild doesn't work with IE 7 script nodes is the root bug.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options I can think of (other than using eval).

- The script could be served from a separate path; setting the `src` of the script element instead of its content should work, even in IE.
- The script to be executed could be attached to the `onload` listener of an image or other element, which can be appended to the document as you are doing with the script element.
- use Function instead of eval. This will at least keep the evaluated code out of the local scope: `new Function(data)();`

Comment: +1 for the idea of directly adding/creating a function. Thanks.