# Set innerHTML and get childNodes is incorrect in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml, child-nodes

This is my code, I want to get childNodes and loop create these tag, But print 2 in IE8

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById('div');
        var code = '<script>alert("hello");<\/script><div>dsd<\/div><script>alert("hi");<\/script>';
        div.innerHTML = code;
        console.log(div.children.length);
        console.log(div.childNodes.length)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presumably there is a compelling reason to bother with IE8? - See if it works without the `<script>` elements, if it does its related to [How do I inject javascript to a page on IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703705/how-do-i-inject-javascript-to-a-page-on-ie-8).

Comment: @AlexK. Thank's, This is my code `code.replace(/<script/g, '<code').replace(/<\/script/g, '</code'); div.innerHTML=code;  div.getElementsByTagName('code') and create script remove code tag`